# The best way to allow users to save their 3rd party API keys for python package

Tags: python, package, pypi, api-key, pythonpath

I'm making a python package that I would like to distribute through pipy that acts as a wrapper for a 3rd party service that needs an api-key. I want the users to use their own (my testing key is **not** in my code) but I don't know the best way for them to provide it for easy use.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643683/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-deal-with-api-keys-when-distributing-a-package) about thoughts on .env variables as well as in-code api-key access.
I have the 2nd option available in my code:

```
from package import class
instance = class(api_key='blablablabla')
instance.do_stuff()
```

and

```
$ package do_stuff --api_key blablablabla --variable2 lalalala
```

and that's fine and dandy for simple scripts, but then the user cannot push their code. How can I make a globally accessible variable that is not a security risk and works from the command line and inside a developer environment?

eg:

```
$ package do_stuff --api_key blablablabla --variable2 lalalala
```

into

```
$ package do_stuff --variable2 lalalala
```

and

```
from package import class
instance = class(api_key='blablablabla')
instance.do_stuff()
```

into

```
from package import class, get_secret

get_secret('{global .env file}')
instance = class()
instance.do_stuff()
```

My thoughts are thus:

1. Make the user do a set-up stage in the terminal if they want to use a global variable (but I worry about cross-platform issues)
2. Make them run a piece of python code once per python-environment (put in python path)
3. make them save a file inside *every* root directory where a project might use this package (this seems sucky to me)

Are there options I am missing? How do I ingrain these options into a python package?

Notes:
assume my package has the structure:

```
 - /root
    - license.txt
    - pyproject.toml
    - readme.md
    - setup.cfg
    - setup.py
    - /function_name
        - file.py
        - __init__.py
        - /tests
            - __init__.py
            - file_test.py
```

Where file.py holds all of the information for the command-line tool and the everyday development functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `config.ini_sample` in the top directory (and push it to your VCS):

```
[DEFAULT]
api_key = <API_KEY>
```

Needless to say, you can create such a file from a script, or just let users copy it themselves from the documentation.
Then the user has to create a copy of the file named `config.ini` and fill in `<API_KEY>`

And then you can use built-in [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), but I would recommend using [`configobj`](https://pypi.org/project/configobj/) like this:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
from package import class

config = ConfigObj("config.ini")
api_key = config["DEFAULT"].get("API_KEY")

instance = class(api_key=api_key)
instance.do_stuff()
```

`configobj` will search for `config.ini` in the patent directories, so even if you have additional directories in your project it will work.

If you use git, then just add `config.ini` to `.gitignore` and don't worry about pushing secret data, only `config.ini_sample`, but do not forget to keep `config.ini_sample` and `config.ini` in sync, so that there won't be such config that will be in the `config.ini` and not in the `config.ini_sample`.

---

From my pov and research that I did, it's the best way to do it, but the other options are:

- To use environment variables
- To have a `config.py` file with values defined in there

Comment: @Travasaurus if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: So this goes back to using an embedded file in the package infrastructure? or in the user's project file infrastructure? Also, I like that this would just require the user to make a simple file! I'm trying to make it as easy as possible for the end user

Comment: @Travasaurus The only thing you need to do is to provide the template + instruction for the user and add the config code I showed, the library you will end up using will search in the user's folder, because the code is running from there. So the only thing user have to do is follow your instructions: add file and use your package

Comment: @Travasaurus hopefully now this answer can [be accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)?